# Can't find variable FlatList or ListView

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to create a list in React Native for Android, and I have this component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class MyList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(<ListView></ListView>);
    }
}
```

However, `ListView` is not recognised: `Can't find variable: FlatList`.

If I change `ListView` to `FlatList`, I get the same issue.

I thought these come with the core React module and that I don't need to import anything else.

Am I missing something?

Comment: you need to import ListView/FlatList and any other component you are planing to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to import `<ListView>` or `<FlatList>` from `react-native` as such:

`import { ListView, FlatList } from 'react-native;`

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstood a couple of things.

First off, if you are going to [destructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the `Component` class from `React`, you should not write your class this way:

`export default class MyComponent extends React.Component`

But instead, write it like so:

`export default class MyComponent extends Component`

Also, the React core provides you with [lifecycles](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#referencing-context-in-lifecycle-methods) etc..

And `react-native` provides you with the native API components that you want to use. (Flatlist, Text, View etc..)

Nevertheless, this snippet should solve your problem:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
+ import { ListView } from 'react-native';

- export default class MyList extends React.Component {
+ export default class MyList extends Component {
    render() {
        return(<ListView></ListView>);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import     {FlatList} from 'react-native';
```

It should work